# Update a component prop from another one

Tags: angular

I have a component A who display a collection of item. I have a component B with filters (search bar, radio) than should update the items in component A. When I log `this.componentA.items` from component B, i see data but visually nothing happen.

Here is what I have:

```
// ComponentA.ts
imports {} from '...'
@Component({...})
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {

  public items: Item[];

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
      this.items = items.map( item => new Item().deserialize(item));
    })
  }
}

// ComponentB.ts
imports {} from '...'
@Component({...})
export class ComponentB implements OnInit {

  constructor(private componentA: ComponentA, private itemService: ItemService) {}

  setItems(items: Item[]): void {
    this.componentA.items = items;
  }

  onCategoryChange(category: string): void {
    this.itemService.getItemsByCategory(category).subscribe( items => {
      this.setItems( items.map( item => new Item().deserialize(item) ))
    }
  }
}
```

[image: An illustration of what i'm tryng to do.]

Comment: Why are you injecting `component A` into `component B` ?

Comment: I throught it could work. But it was just to show you what i've done for the moment. Nowadays it is not liek this anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the items from an Observable of the "itemService".

I would inform the itemService about the filter, than it changes the data and all subscribers get informed.

With that, the service is the royal king over the data.
Component A (that shows the data) just shows data, whatever there comes. A dumb component is a good component.
Component B (the Filter) just informs the service about filtering-Events.

Two more or less dumb components and one service with a bit business (filtering) logic.
A construction like that could be easily covered by UnitTests.

warm regards

Answer (score 0):

To acces this data i gave to componentB a reference of componentA.

```
<componentB [componentA]='compA'></componentB>
<componentA #compA></componentA>
```

and

```
// componentB
...
@Input() componentA: ComponentA;
...
```